# Zero date in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I have some static text files that I need to parse.

In those files I have dates formatted as `Ymd`, `Ym`, `YmdHis` or even `His` but that I can manage.

The problem (output from `artisan tinker`):

```
>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20160415', 'UTC')
=> Carbon\Carbon {#1315
     +"date": "2016-04-15 15:00:22.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "UTC",
   }
>>> $date->format('Ymd')
=> "20160415"

>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', '00000000', 'UTC')
=> Carbon\Carbon {#1076
     +"date": "-0001-11-30 15:00:31.000000",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "UTC",
   }
>>> $date->format('Ymd')
=> "-00011130"
```

When the date is a proper date (2016-04-14 in the example) everything works great but when I get a *zero* date and pass it to `Carbon` it changes it to **30 November of year -1**

Is there a way to teach `Carbon` how to behave in situation like this?

Comment: There is no month or day zero, so it's interpreting it as the last month of the year before, and then the last day of the month before that. What date are you expecting?

Comment: garbage in garbage out, fix your date before you send it to Carbon

Comment: The files are from third party, unfortunately I cannot modify their structure nor how they "visualize" empty/unset date

Comment: `"Is there a way to teach Carbon how to behave in situation like this?"` How should it behave?

Comment: @vascowhite Personally, I think it should either round up or down - maybe a choice. My preference is to round up. E.g. if the day passed is a zero then it becomes the first of the month and not the last day of the previous month

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that the date is greater than the minimum date (`Carbon::minValue()`) and correct it if necessary (e.g. make equal to the minimum date or maybe set it to "Never").

```
>>> $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', '00000000', 'UTC');
=> Carbon\Carbon @-62169953296 {#3106
     date: -0001-11-30 08:31:44.0 UTC (+00:00),
     timezone: "UTC",
   }
>>> if ($date < \Carbon\Carbon::minValue()) $date = \Carbon\Carbon::minValue();
=> Carbon\Carbon @-62135601840 {#3125
     date: 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0 Europe/Warsaw (+01:24),
     timezone: "Europe/Warsaw",
   }
```